# Why does my Vertex Animation shader produce different results in Scene and Game view?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I've been making a game lately, and now I've written a simple vertex animation shader which displaces vertices on some vegetation I have, based on some values.

So far, it's been going OK, but I have some issues when viewing the game side by side with Scene & Game. They produce different results for some reason, and I can't figure it out. Game and Scene cameras are both set to Isometric.

Here's how it looks right now:
[GIF Link](https://gfycat.com/QuickFilthyBoaconstrictor)

On the right (Scene) you can see how the vegetation is supposed to look.

Here's the code bit that is relevant:

```
// Distance from vertex to model origin.
fixed localDistance = distance(v.vertex.xyz, fixed3(0,0,0));

// Some displacement values.
fixed s = sin(_Time.y * _WindY + v.vertex.x);
fixed c = cos(_Time.y * _WindY + v.vertex.z);

// Add the values to the Y of the vertex.
v.vertex.y += _Shakiness * s * c * localDistance * 0.2;
o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);

(Then we pass the vertex on to the fragment, and so on...)
```

Comment: I'm willing to help but that cannot be easily reproduced without a sample project. Can you  provide a [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) project as a zip file?

Comment: Yeah sure, I'll have it up when I get home in a few hours :)

Comment: I'm still waiting. ;)

Comment: Sorry about the delay @zwcloud, here it is:
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xoy35oesvgqct33/TestVertexAnim.rar?dl=0)

It should contain everything you need. Remember to set the Scene and Game view next to each other to see what I meant, as I don't think the Unity editor saves my configuration to the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your models are [dynamically batched](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/DrawCallBatching.html) in the Game view. But in Scene view, it doesn't happen.

> Dynamic batching: for small enough Meshes, this transforms their vertices on the CPU, groups many similar vertices together, and draws them all in one go.
> Because it works by transforming all GameObject vertices into world space on the CPU, it is only an advantage if that work is smaller than doing a draw call.

You can add a [DisableBatching](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-SubShaderTags.html) to your SubShader to disable dynamic batching.

> Some shaders (mostly ones that **do object-space vertex deformations**) do not work when Draw Call Batching is used – that’s because batching transforms all geometry into world space, so “object space” is lost.
>
> DisableBatching tag can be used to incidate that. There are three possible values: “True” (always disables batching for this shader), “False” (does not disable batching; this is default) and “LODFading” (disable batching when LOD fading is active; mostly used on trees).

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much @zwcloud, this was the correct answer!

I ended up adding the line you described in my SubShader Tags:

`"DisableBatching" = "True"`